# Get data from bootstrap select

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I have a simple select with some data:

```
<select id="licenseTypeSelect" name="licenseTypeSelect" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedLicenseType">
  <option data-ng-repeat="licenseType in licenseTypes" value="{{licenseType.licenseTypeId}}">
  {{licenseType.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

And some code for Http.Post:

```
$scope.AddLicenseButton = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/licenses/',
            dataType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                name: $scope.name,
                count: $scope.count,
                buyDate: $scope.buyDate,
                licenseTypeId: $scope.selectedLicenseType
            }
        });
    }
```

My problem is that I can't get selected licenseTypeId.

Comment: That just works: https://jsfiddle.net/zsbdwrk1/2/. Do your objects have a `licenseTypId`?

Comment: My objects have licenseTypeId. When i called http post on browser there are: name, count, buyDate but no licenseTypeId. Request payload: {name: "Test", count: "1", buyDate: "2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"}